# Spring boot with OpenCV

Tags: java, spring, maven, opencv, tomcat

I am trying to use OpenCV in a Spring boot project deployed to Tomcat server  as a war file.

No matter what I try, I keep getting this:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no opencv_java310 in java.library.path
```

I have a classic maven project in which I tested the OpenCV code and it works just fine as long as I put the `opencv_java310` in project classpath. I did the same thing and added this jar to the classpath of my Spring boot project and I also added it to `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib` directory (in order to make it available in the application server).

What else needs to be done to use OpenCV on Tomcat? I am at the end of my wits..

EDIT: When loading the open-cv core library inside a Junit test, it loads correctly:

```
@Test
  public void testOpenCV() {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
  }
```

But If I do the same thing when running the appliation on Tomcat, I get the exception.

Comment: regarding your comments on the answer above, you are using Unix and you have a .so file. Try adding this argument  when running tomcat -Djava.library.path=/home/smajl/Software/opencv/build/lib (add it to the launch configuration).

Comment: I tried running the Tomcat with the following VM argument: -Djava.library.path=/home/smajl/Software/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_java310.so (this is the closest .so file I found) but the exception is still there...

Comment: Try `-Djava.library.path=/home/smajl/Software/opencv/build/lib` instead. With the value you provided, it's probably looking for `/home/smajl/Software/opencv/build/lib/libopencv_java310.so/libopencv_java310.so`...

Comment: You were right, this fixed the setup. Thank you so much!

Comment: Don't specify the .so file in the path, you want to load the entire folder. Try directly with -Djava.library.path=/home/smajl/Software/opencv/build/lib/ as I specified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not talking about the JAR file - it appears that the JAR file is being loaded correctly. However, from the error message it appears that OpenCV uses one or more native libraries (e.g. `.dll` or `lib*.so` files), and it cannot find those.

It's expecting that the property `java.library.path` will point to the location containing the native library `opencv_java310`, but it does not. I'm not 100% sure how to solve this with Eclipse & Tomcat, but you will probably need to find a way to either (a) set the property on Tomcat, or (b) view the value of the property and place the native library in that location (You can get it with `System.getProperty("java.library.path");`). A quick check indicates that you might be able to place it in `tomcat/shared/lib`.

Remember, this is the `.dll` (for Windows) or the `.so` (for OSX, Linux, Unix) file, and **not** the JAR file.

Comment: I printed the java-library-path and this is the result: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib How can I locate the file using that? Sorry for the dummy question but I am really confused now

Comment: EDIT: I also have a working maven project which is running just fine. So I don't understand why there is suddenly this problem in the Spring boot project with the exact same configuration

Comment: It's definitely a bit weird. If you're able to, check the value in the working project and the non-working project and see if there's a difference. Since you appear to be on OSX or Linux, it's likely looking for a file called `libopencv_java310.so` in one of the following locations: `/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64`, `/usr/lib64`, `/lib64`, `/lib`, and `/usr/lib`. There are a few other possibilities, but start here, I'd say.

Comment: Thats weird, the output of the java library path during the junit test run is completely different from the one during runtime: /home/smajl/Software/opencv/build/lib:/home/smajl/Software/opencv/build/lib

Comment: OK, that's looking promising. I have no doubt that one of those folders contains the file we're looking for. The next step is to either (A) add that file to one of the folders, above, or (B) change the configuration for Tomcat so it looks in those folders for the native libraries.

Comment: That is, copy the file `libopencv_java310.so` from `/home/smajl/Software/opencv/build/lib` to one of the folders `/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64`, `/usr/lib64`, `/lib64`, `/lib`, or `/usr/lib`, *OR* add `/home/smajl/Software/opencv/build/lib` to the `java.library.path` property in Tomcat.

Comment: I solved the problem by placing the location in the Tomcat init argument. I am going to try your way (copying the .so file to the correct location) as well since it might be better general solution. Thank you very much for your help and patience!